# Can X-Ray for ArcCatalog be used without Excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, excel

Can X-Ray for ArcCatalog be used without Excel? Our organization went with Libre Office as a budget savings move. Calc in that suite can read/write .xls files, but X-Ray appears to require Excel itself (presumably it's calling Excel.exe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use some functions that don't require using Excel. I've tested to install the add-in on a virtual machine with no Excel installed and it has been added to ArcCatalog. You will be able to use some tools like Reorder Fields, Import using GP and some others, yet most of the reporting tools will be disabled (you'll get an error message when trying to start them).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm looking to use it to import ESRI's Local Government model xml schema. It doesn't seem to be able to do that, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: No, you cannot use .xml schema operations, I am getting the error message as you do.